# Prevent Page Leave on Blazor Client Side

Tags: blazor-client-side

I need some tip of how prevent page lost focus on Blazor Client Side.

Situation is following:

I´m on a page that save or update some data with a form, untill form is not saved I whant to prevent User to leave the page (For example to click a menu or to close the blazor app or refresh the blazor app or to close the browser) to avoid loose of data.

Thankyou a lot in advance for help

Comment: There is an open issue on github about the subject: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14962